# Construction of group structure in T^{*}G where G is a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, co-tangent-space

Well, i'm having problems with the follow construction of Arnold's book "Topological Methods of Hydrodynamics", pg. 51:

"The group $G$ acts naturally on itself by left translations, as well as by right ones.
The left and right shifts commute with each other. Hence, right-invariant vector
(or covector) fields are taken to right-invariant ones under left translations, while left-invariant fields are sent to left-invariant ones by right translations.
Extend every covector on $G$, i.e., an element $\alpha_{g}$ of the cotangent bundle $T^{*}G$ at $g$ ∈ $G$, to the right-invariant section (covector field) $\alpha$ on the group. Define the
action of this covector αg on the phase space $T^{*}G$ as follows. First add to every covector in $T^{*}G$  at $h$ the value of the right-invariant section $\alpha$ at $h$. Then apply
the left shift of the entire phase space $T^{*}G$ by $g$."

In algebraic language , i understood the following, the covector in the end is

$$ L_{g}^{*} (\alpha(h) + \beta_{h})$$
where $\alpha(h) = R_{g^{-1}}^{*}(\alpha_{g})$ a extension of covector $\alpha_{g}$ to entire space and $\beta_{h}$ is any vector of cotangent space at $h$. But the operation only makes sense if we have $h$:
$$ L_{h}^{*}( \alpha(h) + \beta_{h})$$

If someone could clarify....
Thanks !

Comment: I guess $L_g\colon G\to G$ is $h\mapsto gh$ and $L_g^*$ is its derivative? Then I don't understand why you cannot apply $L_g^*$ to $\alpha(h)+\beta_h$, even for $g\neq h$. $L_g^*$ will map a tangent vector at the point $h$ to a tangent vector at the point $gh$. Did you confuse the $h$ in the index for the index of the differential? Maybe it's clearer if we denote the map by $(L_g^*)_h$.

Comment: No, $L_{g}^{*}$ denotes the pullback of the map $L_{g}$. Then, if i am right:
$L_{g}: G \to G$ but $(L_{g})^{*} : T_{gh}^{*}G \to T_{h}^{*}G$, of course considering that we are in cotangent bundle. Then in the last line i have to take a covector cotangent at point $gh$.